# Is it possible to pull all attributes from within a attribute sets folder?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, tabs

This is something I have been wondering, I wish to allow clients to add and take away the products tabs they want quite easily and this is one way I can think of doing it.

Currently my idea is to just programmatically use a loop to pull attributes called customtab1, customtab2, etc but I wanted to make it a bit easier on the client, and inevitably avoid the issue of client misspelling.

I do like the loop idea purely so I can kill the loop at a certain number to keep my designer coworkers happy by ensuring the client doesn't add a million tabs. So if there is no way to do it then there is no loss.

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear. In attribute sets you can set up a folder with attributes in them, is there a way possible on the front end product page to call all attributes by the folder they are placed in? So instead of calling one attribute, you would call the attributes folder and then with a foreach echo out each separate ones textvalue?

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Not particularly clear what it is you are actually trying to do here just from the above.

Comment: Sorry, updated my post. 
I was wishing to see if it would be possible on the product page to pull an attribute folder from the products attribute set, then echo each attributes textvalue with a foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Get attributes by attribute group Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584274/get-attributes-by-attribute-group-magento)

First you need to find the group id

```
$groupId = 1;

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
                ->setAttributeGroupFilter($groupId)
                ->addVisibleFilter()
                ->checkConfigurableProducts()
                ->load();

if ($attributes->getSize() > 0) {
   foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute) {
        /* @var $child Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
        $attributeCodes[] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();                     
   }
}
```